# Unable to navigate based on auth state in flutter-firebase

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase as a backend service in my android app.I am trying to navigate user to the login screen if it is not logged in.I am checking auth state in **main.dart** file.
when app launches I am getting something in my logcat window like:

```
E/FirebaseInstanceId(10239): Failed to resolve target intent service, skipping classname enforcement
E/FirebaseInstanceId(10239): Error while delivering the message: ServiceIntent not found.
```

Below is my code:

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import './home.dart';
import './orders.dart';
import './account.dart';
import './login.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  home: MyTabs(),
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  routes: <String,WidgetBuilder>{
    '/login':(BuildContext context) => Login()
  },
  theme: ThemeData(
    primaryColor: Colors.white,
    primaryColorDark: Colors.grey,
    accentColor: Colors.green
   ),
  );
 }
}

class MyTabs extends StatefulWidget {

@override
_MyTabsState createState() => _MyTabsState();
}


class _MyTabsState extends State<MyTabs> {

FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

int selectedIndex = 0;
final pages = [Home(),Orders(),Account()];

void choosePage(int index){

setState(() {

    selectedIndex = index;
  });
}

@override
void initState() {
super.initState();

  if(auth.currentUser() == null){

     Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed("/login");
  }
}

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Scaffold(
     appBar: AppBar(
       title: Text("Tiffino")
     ),
     body: pages[selectedIndex],
     bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
      currentIndex: selectedIndex,
      fixedColor: Colors.black,
      onTap: choosePage,
      items: [
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
           icon: Icon(Icons.home),
           title: Text("Home")
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
           icon: Icon(Icons.list),
           title: Text("Orders")
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.person),
          title: Text("Account")
         )
        ]
      )      
    );
  }
}
```

Someone please correct me if I did anything wrong in above code.

**THANKS**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `auth.currentUser()` method returns a Future, which means you should use a `then()` method to resolve it or the `await` operator in an async method, instead of instantly checking if it's null.## Heading ##

Try this with async calls, instead of using then and catchError, which would lead to a few more methods to be called:

```
@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getCurrentUser();
}

/// Checks if the user is logged in
_getCurrentUser() async {
    //Notice here the await operator, instead of using then() etc.
    FirebaseUser mCurrentUser = await auth.currentUser();
    if(mCurrentUser != null){
      authSuccess(mCurrentUser);
    } else {
      // not logged in
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed("/login");
    }
}

void authSuccess(FirebaseUser user){
    // User is logged in, do something if needed
}
```

Comment: How can  I get firebase uid once user logged in.

Comment: @Digvijay use the `user` variable that you got, the current user, using `user.uid`. Also, if this answer was right for you, please accept it by clicking the green check under the vote button.

Comment: when i am trying    mCurrentUser = await auth.currentUser();    it is showing error that Undefined name mCurrentUser.

Comment: Got it actually its FirebaseUser mCurrentUser, anyways thanks for helping bro its working fine.

Comment: @Digvijay Yes, sorry! I didn't notice that variable was declared on the outer scope. I fixed it to make sure it works for other people. Glad to help!